# How can I upload a whole folder of PDF files, So that I can skim through each file without having to upload each one of them individually

Tags: vue.js

I have a folder of PDF files, what I want to do is build a small app with directional arrows that when pressed should upload the next PDF file from the uploaded/Selected folder.

I have tried uploading single PDF and I was able to view it, but I'm unable to find any good resource on how to upload a whole directory inside the application for me to not upload each PDF every single time.

I should be able to change my current opened PDF to the next one inside the folder.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this in Vue is as follows:

1. Make a input field and attach the event "v-on:input" with the function that will be called when the input is selected.
2. Don't forget to add "webkitdirectory mozdirectory" for firefox and chrome browsers.
3. Inside the function fetch the input query via "**document.querySelectorAll('input');**". The information of files will be inside files object.